# Best cocoa component to make an interface like html table

Tags: iphone

What's the best component to make an interface like this:

[image: Something like this]

tks

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with it, and how flexible you want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Interface Builder to position 12 buttons exactly as you like. Style them with custom images.

Number their "tag" property from 0 to 11. Create a UIViewController subclass and put a function

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"button %d x %d pressed",sender.tag%4,sender.tag/4);
}
```

in there. Then in IB, link the touchDown action of all buttons to this IBAction. That's all you need!

Comment: I think that @Alexandre has meant table in general, with rows and columns...

Comment: It looked like a keypad to me ;-)

Comment: I meant table in general, actually I have an dynamic content to bind this table...I can have 12, 5, 10 blocks...

Comment: Then you may have to do the math yourself, afaik cocoa doesn't offer such things out of the box. You could abuse the horizontal bars offered by a uitableview, but that will give more pain than it relieves, in the end.